# Is there any app that show to me CPU informations?

Tags: cpu, cache, specifications, register

I would like to understand from some PCs I have which kind of CPU details it got, such as how many register (XMM? 16?), which and how cache, speed, and so on.

Is there such an application? Or for every pc I need to get model and watch online?

Even better if it can do comparisons (such as register/cache of PC1 is faster than PC2).

Comment: if you're using a 64-bit x86 CPU then it always have 16 XMM registers. CPU info programs just give you the instruction sets supported and not every register the CPU has

Comment: @phuclv: also if I compile a software with a 32bit compiler it will use 16 registers?

Comment: no. The instruction set and register set depend on the architecture. As I said above, any CPU info programs will let you know about the architecture. If you want the status of the CPU like registers and flags you need a debugger. But why would you want to know those if you don't debug anything?

Comment: I know that "The registers XMM8 through XMM15 are accessible only in 64-bit operating mode.", but even if I use an application compiled at 32 bit?

Comment: no, 32-bit programs can only access 8 XMM registers. 64-bit programs can access 16 XMM registers and since AVX-512 they have 32 ZMM registers. It's about the architecture and not what you check with a CPU information program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [CPU-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-Z) maybe? That's pretty old and I'm sure there are newer/better options out there, but that's what's I've got on my PC. Still works on Windows 10 so I've never gone hunting for anything else!